# How to add an external library to my project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, pagerslidingtabstrip

I want to use [pagerslidingtabstrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) in my project. Since, it is NOT a jar file. How can I import that?

I read a few articles, and answers on this, but neither of them are clear and all of them are either outdated or complicated.

Can I one suggest the steps clearly please?

Comment: Do you understand the instructions on the README ??? "Include the library as local library project or add the dependency in your build.gradle.

dependencies {
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
}" .... find your project's build.gradle file and add this there...

Comment: It's worth taking some time to read up about the Gradle build system if you are transitioning from Eclipse to Android Studio, as it's a radically different concept (more akin to package management systems). I know it took me a few weeks to really get it down...

Comment: this is a decent introduction : https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to :
File > Project Structure > in modules App go to 'dependencies' tab > click on '+' go for 1 'Library Dependency' > search for 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1' without quotes > ok

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps

Click on File->Import Module->choose to import->choose module and click ok/finish. You are set to go